# Bootstrap for Ember Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog

Im using Bootstrap for [Ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember)'s Modal.
I have a list of items

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="settings/lists">
<table>
<tr><td>Item1<td><td><button {{action 'modal' 'Item1'}} >OpenModal</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item2<td><td><button {{action 'modal' 'Item2'}} >OpenModal</button></td></tr>
<table>
</script>
```

I want to open different modal boxes at each item. The modal needs the name of the template and the controller as object to open. I could pass the name of the controller and template as variabls to the action. But how should i find the object from the name. 
The controller of the list looks like:

```
App.SettingsListsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    manualButtons: [
        Ember.Object.create({title: 'Submit', clicked: "submitManual"}),
        Ember.Object.create({title: 'Cancel', dismiss: 'modal'})
    ],
    actions: {
        submitManual: function() {
            Bootstrap.NM.push('Modal destroyed!', 'success');
            return Bootstrap.ModalManager.close('manualModal');
        },
        modal: function(){
            Bootstrap.ModalManager.open('manualModal', 'Hello', 'hereshouldcomealatemplate', this.manualButtons, controllerasobject);
        }
    }

});
```

**EDIT: Solution**

I have solved the problem like this:

```
<tr><td>Item1<td><td><button {{action 'modal' 'User' 'User'}} >OpenModal</button></td></tr>


    modal: function(model, template){
        var model = this.get('store').find(model);
        this.set("model",model);
        Bootstrap.ModalManager.open('manualModal', 'Hello', template, this.manualButtons, this);
    }
```

I pas the name of the model and the template from the list, i change the SettingLists's model on the fly.
Maybe there is a better solution but it works for now.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at `ember-dialog` addon (http://wheely.github.io/ember-dialog/). It has powerful and ease way to open modal windows with any template or layout you want.

Comment: @ajile thanks. this addon looks great, I will keep it in mind.